# swf file loading with wrong width/height

Tags: html, flash

I have a swf file in an html page.  The dimensions of the swf load correctly when I view it in eclipse's web browser, but when I put the file in internet explorer (10?) the outer perimeter of the window is cropped, so that only part of the swf video is visible while it is playing.  I want users in a wide variety of browsers to be able to load the video without problems.  How can I accomplish this in code?

Here is the code which is causing the problem:

```
<div style="float:right;display:inline-table;">
<OBJECT classid="clsid:bunchalettersandnumbers" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,28;" WIDTH=616 HEIGHT=490>
    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="my_vid.swf"> 
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> 
    <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE="#FFFFFF">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" >
    <EMBED src="my_vid.swf" allowfullscreen="true" quality=high bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  WIDTH=616 HEIGHT=490 TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
    </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT:

As per Aspiro's suggestion, I am using the following code now, but it is still causing the same problem:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("myvid.swf", "myContent", "700", "550", "9.0.0");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myContent" style="border: 3px solid #FFCC66;">Some text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to add a `scale=exactfit` parameter, like: `<param name="scale" value="exactfit">`

Comment: @Cherniv Thank you.  But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Cherniv It is affected by the zoom setting that each individual user specifies in internet explorer. But when I set the dimensions large to accommodate smaller zoom, the video is vertically aligned at center as I zoom out. It would be nice if something managed this regardless of how any given user sets up their zoom settings.

Comment: Have you tried this https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ ?

Comment: @Aspiro Yes.  In fact, that is what I am using now.  But swfobject does not make it clear how to accommodate different user zoom settings in different computers.  When I change the zoom settings in ms explorer, the video either grows a large padding around its edges or the viewing window shrinks to smaller than the video size.  Can you tell me how to avoid these problems so the video is sized to the viewing window no matter what zoom settings the user has on his/her computer?

Comment: By zoom you mean specific browser setting which scale all page for 150% for example or it's all about different window sizes and different resolution?

Comment: @Aspiro By zoom I mean clicking the tools icon in internet explorer and selecting zoom, which results in scaling the entire page to 50% or 150%, etc.  However, I imagine that screen resolution and text size settings also muck it up as well.  How do I control for all these things?  Adding instructions on the page for users to zoom is unprofessional and too verbose.  Is there some way in code to handle all this?  Youtube does not seem to have a problem loading videos the same way no matter how you change your zoom settings, text size settings, or screen resolution settings.

Comment: Now i understand what it's all about. By default settings flash content scale itself sustaining his aspect ratio to fit his html container. If somehow (by users manipulation with window or zoom) aspect ratio of container has changed, you will see zones which at normal ratio a hidden. You should using javascript always control width and height parameters of Object tag;
Zoom is messing with tags parameters. It just scale all content at screen to look smaller but not change they parameters. So you should do it by hands =/

Comment: @Aspiro Thank you. I just added an edit to my original posting above showing the code that I am currently using.  Can you please show me how to alter is to that the video is always fully visible no matter how the user adjusts their zoom settings, screen resolution, or text size, etc.?  If you post your code as an example, and if it works when I test it on my machine, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not declaring an object type, or wrapping your width and height attributes in quotes.

Check your code against the official manual SWF embed syntax. Here's an example on Adobe's site: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/object-tag-syntax-flash-professional.html